# How to bind a textbox to class Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I would like to bind a property in a class one-way to a textbox. but having am trouble, the scenerio is in my code below, getting the string value of test_string into my view. This code I have tried but doesn't seem to work. What do I need to do?

Class with property:

```
namespace config
{
    class tester : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public tester()
        {
        }

        private string test_string;

        public string Test{
            get { return test_string; }
            private set
            {
                test_string = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Test");
            }
        }

        public void dotest(){
            ... do some testing
            Test = "Past point one"
            ... do some more testing
            Test += "Past point two"
            ... do some more testing
            Test += "Finished testing"
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
using config
namespace notif
{
    class t_viewmodel
    {
        public t_viewmodel()
        {
        }

        Tester tester = new Tester();

        public string TestLink
        {
            get { return tester.Test; }
        }

        public void run_test()
        {
            tester.dotest();
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="notif.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="263" Width="539"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:notif" >

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:t_viewmodel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="txtTestMessage" Text="{Binding TestLink}" />
        <Button Content="Do Test" Name="button1" />
        <!--Pretending the button it goes to viewmodels run_test()-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**[EDIT1]**
As the process is running through dotest, it is not until it has finished that the textbox gets populated, is there something I can do to have this update each time the Test property is set?

**[EDIT2]** Altered

```
public void SQLDBAccessTest(string db)
{
    if (test_debug)
        ConnectionTest = "Test started. " + DateTime.Now;

    string conn_string = "";

    try
    {
        conn_string = createConnectionString(db);
        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nConnection string = '" + conn_string + "'";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    try
    {
        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nCreating connection to database...";

        cnn = new SqlConnection(conn_string);

        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nConnection created.";

        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nEstablishing open connection to database...";

        cnn.Open();

        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nEstablished connection to database.";
        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nClosing connection to database...";

        cnn.Close();

        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nConnection closed.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nAn error has occured whilst connecting to the database.\n\t - " + ex.Message;

        throw ex;
    }

    if (test_debug)
        ConnectionTest += "\nTest complete. " + DateTime.Now;
}

private string createConnectionString(string db)
{
    string tempConString = ConStr;

    try
    {
        TestConnSettingsFile();
        setDBDataSourceAndSecurity();

        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nCreating connection string...";

        tempConString = tempConString.Replace("<SERVER>", db_datasource);
        tempConString = tempConString.Replace("<DB>", db);
        tempConString = tempConString.Replace("<SECURITY>", db_security);

        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nCreated connection string.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return tempConString;
}

private bool TestConnSettingsFile()
{
    bool settingsFileExist = false;
    string filePath = "";

    if (test_debug)
        ConnectionTest += "\nTesting for encrypted connection file...";

    try
    {
        string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, "afx.settings");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            settingsFileExist = true;
            xmlSettingsFilePath = filePath;

            if (test_debug)
                ConnectionTest += "\nThe encrypted connection file has been found at: " + filePath;
        }
        else
        {
            if (test_debug)
                ConnectionTest += "\nThe encrypted connection file could not be found at: " + filePath;
            throw new Exception("The encrypted connection file could not be found at: " + filePath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nError occured while testing if encrypted file exists:\n\t - " + ex.Message;
        throw ex;
    }

    return settingsFileExist;
}

private bool setDBDataSourceAndSecurity()
{
    bool result = false;

    if (test_debug)
        ConnectionTest += "\nRetrieving encrypted connection...";

    try
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(xmlSettingsFilePath))
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = null;

            if (test_debug)
                ConnectionTest += "\nReading connection xml file...";

            // Load the file with an XmlTextReader
            reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlSettingsFilePath);
            // Read the File
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //checking where read text is element and and name is “DataSource”
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "DataSource")
                {
                    if (test_debug)
                        ConnectionTest += "\nReading data source...";

                    //assigning ReadElementstring to strCmb1.
                    string datasource = reader.ReadElementString();

                    if (test_debug)
                        ConnectionTest += "\nData source = " + db_datasource;
                }
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Security")
                {
                    if (test_debug)
                        ConnectionTest += "\nReading security...";

                    string security = reader.ReadElementString();

                    if (test_debug)
                        ConnectionTest += "\nSecurity = " + db_security;
                }
            }
            if (test_debug)
                ConnectionTest += "\nClosing connection xml file...";

            reader.Close();
            reader = null;

            if (test_debug)
                ConnectionTest += "\nSuccess retrieving encrypted connection...";

            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (test_debug)
                ConnectionTest += "\nLost connection xml file, could not be found at: " + xmlSettingsFilePath;
            throw new Exception("The configuration file, setup for database connectivity could not be found.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (test_debug)
            ConnectionTest += "\nError occured while setting data source and security:\n\t - " + ex.Message;
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: please check the name of the viewmodel specified in XAML ? i think it should be t_viewmodel

Comment: I`m almost sure that you can solve your problem using a DependencyProperty instead of a common property. Do you know how to use it ? I can provide an example.

Comment: @Vinicius please provide the code so that we can learn lot of things thanks.

Comment: Thanks Abin that was a typo.

Comment: @Vinicius definitely interested in learning more than one way to find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you're binding to is `TestLink`, which is not notifying its change.  Instead, you could expose the `Tester` instance itself:

```
public string Tester
{
    get { return tester; }
}
```

Now you can simply bind to `Tester.Test` -- that does get the change notifications:

```
<TextBox Name="txtTestMessage" Text="{Binding Tester.Test}" />
```

**Edit**

To update the UI continuously with long-running tasks, you'll need to use background threads.  The UI updates (ie, setting "Test") need to be dispatched back to the UI thread.  Here's an example:

```
public void dotest(){
    var dummyAction = new Action( () => Thread.Sleep(1000) );
    var first = new Task(dummyAction);
    var second = new Task(dummyAction);
    var third = new Task(dummyAction);

    first.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Test = Environment.NewLine + "past point one";
        }));
        second.Start();
    });
    second.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Test += Environment.NewLine + "past point two";
        }));
        third.Start();
    });
    third.ContinueWith(task => {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Test += Environment.NewLine + "Finished testing";
        }));
    });
    first.Start();
}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Just changed string to Tester and placed in Mode=OneWay. One extra thing and I have placed this in the question as [EDIT1]

Comment: @Hank sure, you just have to send your task to a background thread.  See my edit above.

Comment: Have I got this right? if I use your suggestion above with the background thread, if some testing takes longer than others then, there is no guarantee that the testing messages will return in consecutive order. Or does it wait until the background thread has completed and then continues to the next test? If I just create the thread to run to update the Test property they will.

Comment: I tried copying pasting your StartNew thread but there is and error in it. Delegate 'System.Action<object>' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: I added some comments in the question. See [EDIT2]

Comment: @Hank maybe I screwed up ... the `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` was meant to dispatch back to the UI thread, but it didn't seem to work correctly when I tested.  Please see my update above (tested) for how to run multiple background tasks sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

In your text box you bind `TestLink` property, but it will not notify property change. instead of that you need to bind `Test` property of `Tester`.

```
Tester tester = new Tester();

//Add property to return your Tester instance.
public Tester TestLink
{
    get { return tester; }
}

//In your XAML bind Test property.
<TextBox Name="txtTestMessage" Text="{Binding TestLink.Test}" />
```

Comment: Yes found out that you need to place in Mode=OneWay or else it throws an error.